# Deploying a Symfony2 back-end REST API and a front-end SPA javascript app

Tags: javascript, git, rest, symfony, heroku

Doing a one page application on one side and a REST API to get the ressources on the other side is something a lot companies do. I've been doing a pet project consisting on a REST API built with the Symfony2 framework and a SPA with Web Components and Polymer. The SPA is doing AJAX requests to get the ressources.

Now I'm wondering how to deploy it on the web. I don't have a lot of experience with deployment and I'd like to know if there are best practices to deploy a web app and where to do it.

I've looked at Heroku and the git push is very convenient but I don't know if (of how) I can push my 2 apps on the same dyno and handle the routing between the two.

Any idea on how to deploy such architecture?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a deployment manager such as [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/). Symfony has it's [own version](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/) which can be useful. Both a written in Ruby, whilst I like using [Magallanes](http://magephp.com/) as it has most of the same functionality but is written in PHP so less dependencies and easier to modify.